# Regex for removing all text of a line after # in Gvim

Tags: regex, vim

I have to remove all text in a line after occurrence of '#' (comments in R language) in following text in Gvim:

```
This line should stay.

  # one (after initial spaces)   - delete this line
    #two (after initial tab) - delete this line
# three (no initial space)       - delete this line
one two #three (after initial words)  - delete text after hash.

This line should also stay.
```

I tried following but these are not working:

```
:%s/#.$//g
:%s/\v#.$//g
:%s/\#.$//g
:%s/\v\#.$//g
```

I presume '.' indicate anything except newline. Where is the problem and how can this be corrected? Thanks.

Comment: You need a quantifier: `:%s/#.*//g`

Comment: For first 3 occurrences, full lines should get deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
:%s/^\s*#.*\n\|#.*//
```

- `^\s*#.*\n` delete line completely if it has optional white-space at start of line and the comment character
- `\|#.*` else, delete from comment character till end of line

Answer (score 1):

Do it in two steps.

1. First find lines having only comments and delete them.

   `:g/^ *#.*$/d`
2. Find comments within the lines and delete them.

   `:%s/#.*/`

Comment: First 3 lines should get deleted, without leaving any blank lines there. For the 4th line, only text after # (including #) needs to be deleted.

Comment: This will remove even those blank lines that were there initially but without any comments. I want only the comment lines to get deleted. The other blank lines should stay.

Comment: @rnso: Check now.

Comment: The first part :g/^ *#.*$/d should be :g/^\s*#/d since tab(s) may be there instead of spaces at start and there is no need to check for characters after #.